# How can I adjust pixel positioning in Sublime Text using the keyboard?

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, emmet

I am using the Emmet LiveStyle Chrome Extension and Sublime Text Package which allows me to make edits to a webpage via Sublime Text and be able to see the changes happening live in the browser. It's like Firebug(or Inspector) without the extra step of having to copy the code back to Sublime Text.

In the Inspector in the browser I am able to select the pixel values of an element and adjust those by using the up or down arrow and therefore finely walk in the values I need. When I try that same approach in Sublime Text, it goes to the previous or next line rather.

How can I adjust pixel positioning in Sublime Text using the keyboard? Is there a combination of keys I need to press perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Emmet plugin has 'Decrement/Increment Number By 0.1/1/10' commands by itself. And 0.1 and 10 has default keyboard shortcuts which are <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down/Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down/Up</kbd> respectively. And you can bind any shortcut to any command as you like. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) for keybinding stuff.